# How to run executable with file input/output in Python using subprocess?

Tags: python, linux, subprocess

I want to run a compiled Fortran code using subprocess in Python. I tried either run() or Popen() but the terminal just hang in there (no output or termination)
Here is the code I tried:

```
bashCommand = 'cp2xsf.x < cp2xsf.in > cp2xsf.out'
# I put cp2xsf.x in local bin, this command is to show that it can be found
process = subprocess.run('which cp2xsf.x', shell=True) 
# files needed for the executable are in ./out
process = subprocess.run(bashCommand.split(), cwd='./out', shell=True)
process = subprocess.Popen(bashCommand.split(), stdout=subprocess.PIPE, cwd='./out', shell=True)
# I used either run or Popen not together
```

Anywhere I did it wrong?

---update---

With the help from Don, it works now. I don't need `split()` if I set `shell=True`. However, if I use `process = subprocess.run(bashCommand.split(), cwd='./out', shell=False)`, it won't work. Not sure why...

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `shell=True`, then I don't think you need to split the bash command. Also, if you know that `cp2xsf.x` exists in the current directory, no need to change the `cwd` argument.  You could try running like:

```
process = subprocess.run(bashCommand, shell=True)
```

Let me know what the output looks like for that one.

Also, do you need to use `subprocess`? Maybe you can try calling:

```
os.system(bashCommand)
```

Although with `os.system()` you will capture only the return code.

Comment: Yes it worked without the split()! Thanks! I have cwd='./out' because the files needed for the executable are in the out directory.

Comment: Awesome bro! I see